# how to make multiple LIKE AND statements inside stored procedured?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

For example, I got an array :

carBrand: 'ford','volve','honda'

I would like to search a field which contained all elements of it, just like :

```
SELECT * FROM car_company WHERE car_company.brandStory LIKE '%ford%' AND car_company.brandStory LIKE '%volve%' 
AND car_company.brandStory LIKE '%honda%';
```

And the array is an input parameter outside stored procedure

So far, I got two approachs nearly but still not good to me：

1. use REGEXP

for example:

```
SET carBrand = 'ford|volve|honda'; //input parameter
SELECT * FROM car_company WHERE car_company.brandStory REGEXP carBrand;
```

But the code make the OR statement actually, all I want is AND statement.

2. use full-text index

for example:

```
SET carBrand = '+ford +volve +honda';  //input parameter
SELECT * FROM car_company WHERE MATCH (brandStory) AGAINST (carBrand IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This is the closest solution I have found，but I really don't want to set the full-text index.

Is there any other solution ? Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stored procedure

```
USE `testdb`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `BuildSelect`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `testdb`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BuildSelect`(IN carbrand TEXT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE brand TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE brandlength INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE Tempbrand TEXT DEFAULT NULL;



    SET @Selectstr = "SELECT * FROM car_company WHERE";
    iterator:
    LOOP
        IF LENGTH(TRIM(carbrand)) = 0 OR carbrand IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE iterator;
        END IF;
        SET brand = SUBSTRING_INDEX(carbrand,',',1);
        SET Tempbrand = CONCAT(" car_company.brandStory LIKE '%",TRIM(brand),"%'");
        IF brandlength > 0 THEN
            SET Tempbrand = CONCAT(" AND",Tempbrand);
        END IF;
        SET @Selectstr = CONCAT(@Selectstr,COALESCE(Tempbrand,''));
        SET carbrand = SUBSTRING_INDEX(carbrand,',',-(LENGTH(carbrand) - LENGTH(REPLACE(carbrand, ',', '')) ));
        SET brandlength = brandlength +1;
    END LOOP iterator;
    SET @Selectstr = CONCAT(@Selectstr ,";");
    PREPARE  id  FROM @Selectstr;
    EXECUTE id;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE id;
    #SELECT @Selectstr;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Would run with this call

```
 call BuildSelect('Ford,Audi,Mercedes');
```

Run this query

```
SELECT * FROM car_company 
WHERE car_company.brandStory LIKE '%Ford%' 
      AND car_company.brandStory LIKE '%Audi%' 
      AND car_company.brandStory LIKE '%Mercedes%';
```

Comment: Thank you nbk, this is the solution all I want!